# Jenkins Single job deploying to Multiple Server using jboss as maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, jboss, jenkins

I have a jenkins job deploying to multiple servers.

As a build step -  clean install

If build succeeds

- post build step1 -  invoke top level maven targets -  jboss-as:deploy
  -Dhostname=A
- post build step2 -  invoke top level maven targets -  jboss-as:deploy
  -Dhostname=B

I want to have separate emails to be send for each post build step for success and failure.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can someone comment on this?

Comment: Can anyone help me with this? Stuck with this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated?